# Scoring unsupervised data

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, regression, unsupervised-learning, scoring

Given the features and details of a house listed for selling, i'd wish to calculate a score   based on the accuracy, completeness, genuineness and authenticity provided by the owner.According to me, this is a regression problem (Please correct me if wrong, i am new in this domain). So, we'd need a labelled data for training. But, we don't have any score for the existing data.
I am currently thinking about generating scores for a certain number of observations(lets say 1000) manually. And feed this dataset into a Deep Neural Network.
Suggest alternative solutions and improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is indeed a regression problem and you are correct that you would need labelled data. Manually labelling is a good suggestion but for a DNN specifically you would probably need more data than just 1000 records. There are other methods you could try though. Based on the types of features I suspect you may have, it could be worth considering a tree based model!